# Algorithm for detecting prime powers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms, factorization

While reading Peter Shor's paper *Polynomial-Time Algorithms for Prime Factorization and Discrete Logarithms on a Quantum Computer*, I came across the following quote:

> "This scheme will thus work as long as $n$ is odd and not a prime power; finding factors of prime powers can be done efficiently with classical methods."

I have two questions:

(1) How does one efficiently determine if a given number $N$ is a prime power, and

(2) How does one efficiently determine the factorization of a prime power?

(Note: I have included these as separate questions since I am aware that many of the standard  algorithms for determining a number is composite will not necessarily produce a proper factor.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If N is a prime power it is of the form $p^i$ where  $i \leq \log_2(N)$. One can thus compute each of the first $\log_2(N)$ roots of $N$, and test if the resulting number is (first an integer) and then if it is a prime using the [AKS algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) (although perhaps Shor meant to use a randomized test, such as  [Miller–Rabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test), as the paper pre-dates AKS). Obviously if $N$ is a prime power this will produce the factorization.

Comment: Ha, you type faster!

Comment: Perfect! I was hoping the answer was that simple. Thanks!

Comment: You don’t need AKS or any randomized test. If you want to factor a number (or test it for primality: in fact, the AKS algorithm itself starts by such a check), you can as well check for any perfect powers rather than just prime powers: if you succeed, you get a proper factor of $N$, otherwise you are guaranteed that it is not a prime power.

Comment: @Emil, I agree that one can easily test if a number is a perfect power, however the question was "How does one efficiently determine if a given number is a prime power?"

Comment: Yes, but from the context it is clear that that’s not what Shor actually uses in the paper.

Answer (score 12):

See Dan Bernstein's paper, ``Detecting perfect powers in essentially linear time.'' Mathematics of Computation 67 (1998), 1253--1283, available at http://cr.yp.to/papers.html#powers.  Here "linear" means "linear in log n".

Answer (score 10):

If $n = p^k$ with $p \geq 2$ then $k \leq \log_2 n$. For each candiate $k$, we can compute the integral part of $m = \lfloor n^{1/k} \rfloor$ in time polynomial in $\log_2 n$, and then test whether the $n = m^k$. This gives a time complexity polynomial in $\log_2 n$, also known as "efficient".